# Is there a way in moshi to mark a field in the response body template as optional?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I am currently working on an android app where I am using moshi to parse the response from retrofit as json. But I have the problem that one or more fields in the response body are sometimes included and sometimes not, based on what data you are getting back.
For example:

sometimes you get back this (case 1):

```
{
   "fieldAaa": 33,
   "fieldBee": 2
}
```

and sometimes this (case 2):

```
{
   "fieldAaa": 33
}
```

My data class for the request body would currently look like this

```
data class RequestBodyTemplate(
        val fieldAaa: Int,
        val fieldBee: Int
)
```

so there is no distinction between the 2 cases mentioned above, which results in a crash when case 2 is present (meaning fieldBee is missing in the response)
**Is there a way in moshi to mark this field as optional maybe(or other solution), or is there a solution in retrofit?**

Comment: make it nullable

Comment: Thanks you, it works. I tried it before but I made a mistake while testing which is why I thought it does not work like this.